# Sentence Structure With "So"

Tags: conjunctions, punctuation

A sentence structure question:

1. "It was getting late, so we went home."
2. "It was getting late.  So, we went home."

Should "so" be preceded by a comma or period?  Is one of them wrong?

Comment: Answered here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30436/when-do-we-need-to-put-a-comma-after-so

Comment: @CoolHandLouis No, I'm afraid not.  This question is about whether to use a comma or period before *so*.  Unlike the question you've linked to, it is not about the comma after *so*.

Comment: @snailplane  Do both sentences mean the same thing?  I looked up a couple of grammar books and got the feeling that the sentence 2 would likely be less formal/standard than sentence 1.

Comment: "Just so, you know." "Just so you know, ..."

Answer (score 2):

> "It was getting late, so we went home."

is fine.

The second example does not need a comma:

> "It was getting late. So we went home."

This is fine too, since each phrase can stand on its own.
Which one is best would depend on written or spoken context.

"so" as used in these examples is a conjunction. It's [Sense 8](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/so) in Collins Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

When *so* means *consequently* and follows the condition or situation which prompts it, it is preceded by a comma within the same sentence.

The second example is incorrect in my opinion.